# Runtime Error 3065 "Cannot execute a select query" in VBA SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, calculated-field

I'm having some problems with a VBA script I'm creating and I thought here would be the best place to ask. I will give some background:

I am writing this program as a lot of my clients go against the regular issued documents from my countries tax office and pay cash in hand, and then get me to calculate the amount of tax on that particular amount. It is a fair bit of paperwork figuring that out manually, so I am writing an application that does this, and a fair amount more. The script below is at the heart of what needs to be done.

For the first use case I have essentially created a single-use form in Access - nothing is written, it is just for a temporary calculation and being sent to the printer - to calculate holiday pay.

As I cannot perform a SQL lookup in a calculated cell, I am running a VBA script to do the heavy lifting for me, passing the three entered values as arguments.

However, I cannot seem to get rid of runtime error 3075, and I cannot for the life of me figure out where it is coming from. I have traced it down to the SQL statement but I can't find where there would be an operator error. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
    Option Compare Database

    Public Function DetermineTax(CurrentDate As Date, CurrWageType As String, CalcNetWages As Currency)

    'Checks whether required fields are blank

    If Not (IsDate(CurrentDate)) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (CurrWageType = "") Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If (CalcNetWages <= CCur(0#)) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim strSQL As String

    'Calculates tax based on (-((n-b)/(a-1))-n) formula, where all WHERE arguments have been met.

    strSQL = 
    "SELECT FIRST (ROUND(((-(CalcNetWages-tblWageRate.CoefficientB)/(tblWageRate.CoefficientA-1))-CalcNetWages))) " & _
    "FROM tblWageType INNER JOIN tblWageRate " & _
    "ON tblWageType.WageTypeID = tblWageRate.fk_WageTypeID " & _
    "WHERE tblWageRate.TaxYearStart <= CurrentDate And " & _
    "tblWageRate.TaxYearEnd >= CurrentDate And " & _
    "tblWageType.WageType = CurrWageType And " & _
    "tblWageRate.Net >= CalcNetWages;"

    CurrentDb.Execute Query:=strSQL, Options:=dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

    'DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

    End Function
```

Of course if there is any further questions I'll be around to answer them.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Urgh, I've been looking at this code for too long. The ROUND function needed to be encapsulated in brackets. That got rid of error 3075. I have amended my code above to where it is now.

However now I am receiving error 3065 "Cannot execute a select query". With some preliminary Googling it seems that I cannot use a SELECT field in a form, but I don't think that should make a difference as I am calling it in a module. I will attempt further tomorrow as I am off to bed, but in the meantime does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What means "SELECT FIRST ..."? I have not seen such operator, maybe you meant "SELECT TOP 1 ..."

Comment: SELECT FIRST should select the first result returned. As there will almost certainly be more than one result where tblWageRate.Net is larger than CalcNetWages, I have to select the first one to return the correct coefficients. 

I just tried SELECT TOP 1 and it changed the error to 2342 (A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement)

Comment: I never actually replace CurrentDate, CurrWageType or CalcNetWages. They are user-entered variables that need to be passed in to get a match for the SQL query.

The result will be written to a text box, however as I want this code to work in many different forms I want to make sure it is actually returning the correct values first.

Comment: TOP 1 is the standardized syntax. Access has a special flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem during the week. I believe the problems were a) the way dates were handled and b) missing quotation marks.

This also includes the code that I have that a) called the function in question and b) appended it to a table.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnCalc_Click()

Me.txtWeeklyTax = CalcNetTax(Me.txtWeeklyNet, Me.txtDatePaid, Me.cmbTaxType)


End Sub

Private Sub btnInsertRec_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO tblPayment  "
strSQL = strSQL & "            (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        fk_EmployerID,  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        fk_EmployeeID,  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        PaymentDate  ,  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        fk_WageTypeID,  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        NetPayment   ,  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        TaxPayable  "
strSQL = strSQL & "            ) "
strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES  "
strSQL = strSQL & "            (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.cmbEmployer & "',  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.cmbEmployee & "',  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.txtDatePaid & "',  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.cmbTaxType & "',   "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.txtPropNet & "',   "
strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.txtPropTax & "'   "
strSQL = strSQL & ");"

'strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES  "
'strSQL = strSQL & "            (  "
'strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.[cmbEmployer] & "',  "
'strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.[cmbEmployee] & "',  "
'strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.[txtDatePaid] & "',  "
'strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.[cmbTaxType] & "',   "
'strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.[txtPropNet] & "',   "
'strSQL = strSQL & "                        '" & Me.[txtPropTax] & "',   "
'strSQL = strSQL & ");"

Debug.Print strSQL

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
Call cmdReset_Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmbEmployer_AfterUpdate()
  Me.cmbEmployee.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
On Error GoTo ResetError
Dim Frm As Form, Ctl As Control

Set Frm = Me
For Each Ctl In Frm
Ctl.Value = Null
Next Ctl

ResetError:
If Err = 2119 Or Err = 438 Or Err = 2448 Then
Resume Next
ElseIf Err > 0 Then
MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
End If
End Sub
```

Actual tax function...

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function CalcNetTax(NetPay As Currency, PayDate As Date, TaxType As Integer) As Currency

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT     FIRST (ROUND((-(" & [NetPay] & "-tblWageRate.[CoefficientB])/(tblWageRate.[CoefficientA]-1)-" & [NetPay] & "))) AS TaxPayable "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM       tblWageType  "
strSQL = strSQL & "           INNER JOIN tblWageRate  "
strSQL = strSQL & "           ON         tblWageType.[WageTypeID] = tblWageRate.[fk_WageTypeID] "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE      (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                            tblWageRate.[TaxYearStart]  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 <= " & SQLDate([PayDate]) & "  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "           AND  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                            tblWageRate.[TaxYearEnd]  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 >= " & SQLDate([PayDate]) & "  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "           AND  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                            tblWageType.[WageTypeID]  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 = " & [TaxType] & "  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "           AND  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 (  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                            tblWageRate.[Net]  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                                 >= " & [NetPay] & "  "
strSQL = strSQL & "                      )  "
strSQL = strSQL & "           );"

Debug.Print strSQL
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
rs.MoveFirst
CalcNetTax = CCur(rs.Fields(0))

rs.Close
db.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Function

Private Function SQLDate(vDate As Variant) As String
        If IsDate(vDate) Then
            SQLDate = "#" & Format$(vDate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
        End If
End Function
```